# Log4J2 property substitution - default

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I just wonder if there is any way to provide default value for property substitution in LOG4J?

I want to pass file path in java system property and then use it with "${env:mySystemProperty}". But what if developer forgets to set this property? Then I would like to have some meaningful default value defined in log4j2.xml.

Any idea how to achieve this functionality?

EDIT:

The env substitution does not work for me:

standalone.conf

```
-DoauthLoginLogPath=/path/oauth2.log
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="${env:oauthLoginLogPath}" immediateFlush="true">
<Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="${sys:oauthLoginLogPath}" immediateFlush="true">
```

I can see in wildfly console the property, I restarted server but I cannot get it done.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Default Property map**

Looking at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution
you can specify a default property map in the configuration file. That takes this form:

```xml
<Configuration status="debug">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="oauthLoginLogPath">default/location/of/oauth2.log</Property>
  </Properties>
  ...
  <Appenders>
    <Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="${sys:oauthLoginLogPath}">
    ....
</Configuration
```

Then, if you start your app with system property `-DoauthLoginLogPath=/path/oauth2.log`, the File appender `fileName` value will first be looked up in system properties, but if that fails, it will fall back to the property defined in the `Properties` section at the top of the log4j2.xml configuration file.

**Inline**

A second way is to provide the default value inline:

```xml
<Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="${sys:oauthLoginLogPath:-default/location/of/oauth2.log}">
```

Generally, all Log4j2 lookups follow this pattern: `${type:key:-defaultValue}`.

**Env vs sys**

By the way, the `env` prefix is for environment variables (like %PATH% on Windows), and is not related to `sys`, which is Java system properties. See also http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

Comment: I don't know if it worked in a previous version, but this does not work anymore. You have to use ':-' in the property to define the default value.

Comment: In case some one is struggling with setting the default value inline. Please note that the value is what comes after the hyphen, e.g. if my default path is `/var/log/myfile.log`, then I would write `${sys:oauthLoginLogPath:-/var/log/myfile.log}`

Answer (score 22):

You can use the same `${sys:propName:-default}`syntax. Notice the ':-', it is is called "***variable default value delimiter***". The *default* value for the "*variable default value delimiter*" is `:-`, as in *bash* and other **nix* shells.

You can read more about this in the Log4j 2 documentation for the [*StrSubstitutor*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html) class.

To use the same example:

```xml
<Configuration status="debug">
  ...
    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="File" name="File"
                  fileName="${sys:oauthLoginLogPath:-default/location/of/oauth2.log}">
        ....
    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that default values are resolved at the time the log4j2.xml file is loaded. It doesn't work to set default values for e.g. variables to be injected via the thread context.

Comment: Correction: works, but one has to add a second `$`, e.g. `$${ctx:username:-UNKNOWN}` :)