# Log4j2: Change Pattern based on environment variable

Tags: java, log4j2

I'd like to make configurable the value of my `log4j2.xml`'s `<Pattern/>` element.

Nominally we have this pattern:

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%xEx{filters(${filters})}%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

One user of our code wants a different Pattern (they have a constraint that "log entries must not span multiple lines — even if they have stack traces"), which looks like this:

```
<Pattern>%replace{%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%xEx{filters(${filters})}}{(\n|\r)+}{, }%n</Pattern>
```

Each user can specify their own Environment independently, so I felt that was a good way to let them choose their Pattern.

I know that it is possible in `<Pattern/>` elements to [specify the pattern using Environment Variables](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup). For example:

```
<Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] $${env:USER} %m%n</Pattern>
```

I also know that [it is possible to specify a default/fallback value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37804992/5257399), like so: `$${env:USER:-default}`. This is good, since I would like the nominal pattern to be the default, and work without specifying a bespoke environment.

So, I tried this pattern:

```
<Pattern>$${env:LOG_SYSOUT_PATTERN:-%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%xEx{filters(${filters})}%n}</Pattern>
```

My understanding was that it would allow a user to specify a pattern in `LOG_SYSOUT_PATTERN`, but fallback to the usual Pattern otherwise.

I expected my log entries to look like this:

```
2016-09-27 10:47:32,073 INFO c.b.b.a.Engine [main] Sleeping AuditEngine for 1000 ms
```

But it seems to have failed. What I actually get with my pattern is this:

```
${env:LOG_SYSOUT_PATTERN:-2016-09-27 10:47:29,642 INFO c.b.b.a.Engine [main] Sleeping AuditEngine for 1000 ms
}
```

Is the use-case that I have described, beyond the limitations of log4j2's string interpolation?

Obviously it is possible for me to instead use environment variables to point to a different `log4j2.xml` file altogether, but I would prefer a solution which does not involve maintaining and deploying two files for the sake of one bespoke difference for one user.

We use Log4j 2.5 and SLF4J 1.7.16.

Comment: this issue is tracked here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2968
please vote if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the pattern
try it

`<Pattern>$${env:LOG_SYSOUT_PATTERN}:-%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%xEx{filters(${filters})}%n</Pattern>`

Comment: I think this assertion is incorrect. As explained in my question, we already know that the syntax for macro expansion with a fallback value is: `$${env:USER:-default}`, yet your suggestion is to move the fallback _outside_ the brackets. That will definitely not be valid. In fact, I have tried running your Pattern. It interprets the `:-` as a literal. Curiously though, the undefined macro does not get expanded at all, and instead gets printed literally:

`${env:LOG_SYSOUT_PATTERN}:-2016-09-27 14:45:59,425 INFO c.b.b.a.Engine [main] Sleeping AuditEngine for 1000 ms`