# Log4j : How to create default values in properties file

Tags: java, properties, log4j, rollingfileappender, fileappender

I have the following file appender

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${myFileLoc}/log/mylog.log
```

However, I want to make sure it still functions properly if someone forgets to set the system property. Is there a way to specify a default value in the properties file?

I do not want to change the log4j.xml in any way. I just want to change the log4j properties file or if possible, make some code change to reflect what i need.

For example, if possible, i can check for the system property in the code and if it is not set, then pass the default value to the logger. Is that feasible?

Comment: I'm just trying to clearly understand this questions. Are you using both xml file and properties file ?

Comment: i dont have access to the log4j xml file. i can only work with the log4j.properties file

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define it like this in properties file. See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties).

```
property.myFileLoc = target/rolling/rollingtest.log
```

For property substitution in xml file see [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution). Also please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029761/1849366).

Comment: thanks, so does this go in log4j.properties? also how do i check and replace?

Comment: I haven't tried this. Please see the docs that I have linked.