# How do I customize a GELF appender for log4j2?

Tags: log4j2, graylog, gelf, graylog3

We have a log4j2-graylog.xml file that we use to bridge our log4j output to GrayLog 3.0 using the `biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j2` package.  This config file is based on this [example](https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/log4j-2.x.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" packages="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Gelf name="gelf"
              host="10.13.10.192"
              port="12201"
              version="1.1"
              extractStackTrace="true"
              filterStackTrace="true"
              mdcProfiling="true"
              includeFullMdc="true"
              maximumMessageSize="8192"
              originHost="swarm"
              additionalFieldTypes="environment=String,application=String">
            <Field name="timestamp" pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}"/>
            <Field name="level" pattern="%level"/>
            <Field name="simpleClassName" pattern="%C{1}"/>
            <Field name="className" pattern="%C"/>
            <Field name="server.fqdn" pattern="%host{fqdn}"/>
            <Field name="threadName"/><!-- didn't seem to work -->
       
            <!-- This is a static field -->
            <Field name="application" literal="PISM-webapp"/>
        </Gelf>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.xxx" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="gelf"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It basically works.  Our Java calls to log4j logging show up in GrayLog.

Based on the information from [here](https://logging.paluch.biz/default-fields.html), it seems like it ought to be easy to add a field that captures the thread data, but our attempts thus far have failed.  Also we would like a field that reports the value of a certain environment variable.  Can anybody tell me how to do either of these two things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [information](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) from the log4j2 manual, I was able to get the thread name by adding `threadName` to the `additionalFieldTypes` and using a `%t` pattern specifier like so:

```xml
<Gelf name="gelf"
      host="10.13.10.192"
      port="12201"
      version="1.1"
      extractStackTrace="true"
      filterStackTrace="true"
      mdcProfiling="true"
      includeFullMdc="true"
      maximumMessageSize="8192"
      originHost="swarm"
      additionalFieldTypes="environment=String,application=String,threadName=String,fbHost=String">
    ...
    <Field name="threadName" pattern="%t"/>
```

However, when I tried to use the syntax provided on the page to retrieve the value of an environment variable like so:

```xml
<Field name="fbHost" pattern="$${env:LB_COOKIE_VALUE}" />
```

I didn't get the value of the `LB_COOKIE_VALUE` environment value in GrayLog.  Instead, I got the literal string - "${env:LB_COOKIE_VALUE}".  This StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028399/log4j2-property-substitution-default) gave enough information to debug the problem. When I provided a default value,

```xml
<Field name="fbHost" pattern="$${env:LB_COOKIE_VALUE:-unset_env_LB_COOKIE_VALUE}" />
```

I got "unset_env_LB_COOKIE_VALUE" in the output, indicating that the environment variable was not set.  However, the Java system property was set, so

```xml
<Field name="fbHost" pattern="$${sys:LB_COOKIE_VALUE:-unset_sys_LB_COOKIE_VALUE}" />
```

provided the value I was looking for.

Comment: The fact that $${sys:LB_COOKIE_VALUE} worked indicates that you had that as a system property, not as an environment variable.

Comment: @rgoers - Yeah, I came to realize that the hard way.  What helped was finding out how to print out a message when the environment variable wasn't found.